# AWS Autocaling scheduled action - daily occurrence action disappears and capacity not reset

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I want to create an autoscaling scheduled action.
The autoscaling policy is initially set to 2 desired, 2 min and 6 max.

Every day at 7 am CST I want to bring the settings up for 4 desired, 4 min and 6 max and at 6 pm CST I want it to go back to its original scaling settings (2,2,6).

To test that this works, in the AWS autoscaling dashboard I created a schedule action with the following: min-4, max-6, desired-4, recurrence-every day. For the start time I tested it with the current date and ten minutes ahead of the current time. For end time I put in 15 minutes after the start time with the same date. It gave a cron of 55 12 * * *

I created the action and saw it in the scheduled actions list. Fast forward 40 minutes and the autoscaling settings are at 4 desired, 4 min and 6 max therefore the action did get triggered but was never reset back to the original settings. 
The questions I have -

1 - I would assume that after the scheduled action is done and past its end time that it would reset the autoscaling settings back to there original settings - which would have brought it back to 2 desired, 2 min and 6 max. Why would it have the end time option if this is not true?

2 - After the scheduled action ran for that day the entry under scheduled actions was gone. This would lead me to believe that it would not run again the next day. I chose the recurrence to be "every day". I would assume that every day would mean run this action every day at the times that were selected. Should it keep the action in the actions list if this was true and to run every day?

3 - What is the difference between every day recurrence and every week?

Also would there be anyway to set it up custom for weekends. Ideally I would like the following setup:
Monday through Friday between 7AM and 6PM CTS : 4 desired, 3 min and 6 max 
Monday through Friday between 6PM and 7AM CTS : 2 desired, 2 min and 6 max 
All of Saturday and Sunday : 2 desired, 2 min and 6 max

Any help is appreciated!

Ernie

Answer (score 1):

From [PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction.html):

> **EndTime**
>
> The date and time for the recurring schedule to end. Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling does not perform the action after this time.

So, the `EndTime` tells it when to end the recurrence. For example, you could tell it to repeat every Tuesday until 1-July by setting the EndTime to 1-July.

Since you set the EndTime to 15 minutes later, then the recurrence stopped and no further repeats happened. So, given your requirements, you should **leave EndTime empty**.

From [Scheduled Scaling for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html):

> **To scale on a recurring schedule**
>
> You can specify a recurrence schedule, in UTC, using the Unix cron syntax format. This format consists of five fields separated by white spaces: [Minute] [Hour] [Day_of_Month] [Month_of_Year] [Day_of_Week]. For more information about this format, see [Crontab](http://crontab.org/).

So, you can specify the Days of the Week that you'd like the event to recur.

By the way, it's probably best to **only change the Minimum value**, without changing the **Desired** value. The reason for this is that the Auto Scaling group might be relatively busy at the scale-in time. When things get quieter, the group will scale-in based on rules. If you change the Desired at such a time, it might not be able to handle the current load.

Comment: Thanks so much John! That explained it perfectly.